# Marking the head reference to the tail of the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

The iterative way of reversing a linked list is very easy way to do. I tried to understand the recursive way by going through the below link

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-reverse-the-nodes-of-a-linked-list/

```
void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node* first;
    struct node* rest;

    /* empty list */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
       return;   

    /* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
    first = *head_ref;  
    rest  = first->next;

    /* List has only one node */
    if (rest == NULL)
       return;   

    /* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
    recursiveReverse(&rest);
    first->next->next  = first;  

    /* tricky step -- see the diagram */
    first->next  = NULL;          

    /* fix the head pointer */
    *head_ref = rest;              
}
```

We first move the pointer to the tail of the linked list.
During stack unwinding we stitch the links reversely.
But for all the stack unwinding calls, *headref = rest . So as first is changing during the stack unwinding to the previous stack value, why doesnt the rest too didnt change. I created 4 nodes and viewed the values through the gdb. The rest values during stack unwinding remained constant but the first values are changing. Why is it rest not changing.

Answer (score 1):

While thinking in terms of changing pointers and values is a good way
to think about iterative programs, it is a confusing way to look at
recursive programs, because each recursive call creates its own local
variables, all with the same names, but possibly different values.

With a recursive function it is more helpful to assume that it works correctly for input of size `n`, and then verify its correctness for input of size `n+1`. If the "base case" (size 0 or 1) is covered, this then proves that it works for all inputs

In your case, let's suppose that `recursiveReverse` works OK for lists of length 3, and let's feed it a list of length 4 `a->b->c->d` by
calling `recursiveReverse(&p)` where `p=a`

Both `first->next` and `rest` will be `b`, hence point to a 3-element list `b -> c -> d`, so (by our assumption)
`recursiveReverse(&rest)` will correctly reverse this list. After the
call, `rest` has changed value (from `b` to `d`) and now points to this reversed list `d->c->b`

`first->next` is still the same pointer `b` as before the call, and therefore now points to the *end* of the list.
Thus, `first->next->next =  first` attaches `first` to the end of this reversed list, which then becomes `d->c->b->a`) 
As `first` is now the end of the list, we now need `first->next = NULL`.  The final step is to change `*head_ref` (from `a` to `d`), so, after returning from `recursiveReverse(&p)`, `p` will have changed from `a` to the new head of the list, `d`.

This shows that whenever the function works correctly for n-element
lists, it works correctly for n+1-element lists. The base case is easy,
so whe have shown that it works for all lists.

Now, why don't you see `rest` changing value in your debugger? Because
its value is only ever changed by the function call
`recursiveReverse(&rest)`.  Before you recursively call
`recursiveReverse` it has one value, after you return from it it has
another, you don't see it changing when stepping in and out of each function call. The assignment that changes its value is actually the very last (`*head_ref = rest`) before the function returns, but the assignee is called `head_ref` in this stack frame, not `rest` (as it was called in the stack frame of the caller)

This is the "same names, but different values" confusion I mentioned above.